# What should be done with [mocha]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) refers to the [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) JavaScript test framework. There is also a [Mocha](http://gofreerange.com/mocha) for Ruby mocking and stubbing.

Some questions assume [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) is for the Ruby library - like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4395574/1454117).

Should [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) be split into [mocha-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha-javascript) and [mocha-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha-ruby)? Or should [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) just be removed from questions referring to the Ruby library?

Comment: Make hot chocolate?

Comment: @dilbert All programmers deserve high quality beverages.

Comment: Doing this has been on my todo list for a while. The conservative thing to do would be to have two tags. Unsure about the proper naming convention to use.

Comment: can those uses coexist peacefully, considering that one group will also be tagged ruby and the otherjavascript? Are there many that proudly bear all three tags and would / would not use all four after such a change?

Comment: @LeviStanley Exactly why hot chocolate is great! Especially with marshmallows.